# Use enviroment variables in docker-compose.yml file in VueJS application

Tags: vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables, devops

Please tell me how you can pass environment variables to the **VUE** application from the `docker-compose.yml` file. For some reason, after the `yarn build` command in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the application sees only **env variables** that are written in the `"env.production"` file

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  develop_dashboard_frontend:
  image: some_image:latest           
  container_name: develop_dashboard_frontend
  environment:
    VUE_APP_API_URL: "some_api_URL"
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8016:80"
  restart: always
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The vue-cli/webpack will pack everything at build. So you have to pass that env variables when you build the image not when you run image.

Comment: @user-28 Do you mean in the file `.gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: Yes at build stage. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58913540/2438933

Comment: @user-28 in this case, I cannot separate the environment into dev and prod

Comment: You can create separate job for dev and prod. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051640/how-to-do-a-single-build-with-gitlab-for-vue-application-with-multiple-env-file

Comment: @user-28 I have someerror. `jobs:docker dev dashboard config contains unknown keys: enviroment`

Comment: You mean enviroment or environment?

Comment: @user-28 Sorry, I sent wrong error. I also have error: "jobs: dev dashboard:environment name can't be blank"
In `.gitlab-ci.yml` I wrote :
`environment: NODE_ENV: development`

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this will be difficult for comment. I don't understand your code here. I think you should ask a new question with your gitlab-ci file and that error.

Comment: @ user-28 can I text to you in email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222165/discussion-between-user-28-and-n-ayaz).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put dashes (`-`) before each environment variable you want to specify, like you did it with `ports` in your example.
Refer to: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: 'some_image:tag'
    environment:
     - VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value
```

You also need to distinguish between build time and runtime environment variables.
You can supply environment variables for your build, but that might not be saved for the runtime. It really depends on your build (I'm not familiar with `yarn build`).
However, I recommend using supplying the env variables for run time.

Just define them in the `yaml` as you tried.

Using `$ docker stack deploy` or `docker-compose up` it should work.

Comment: I added a dashes (`-`) , but it doesn't work, then I tried to write `- NODE_ENV="development" ` and it doesn't work either